# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation); "__TMaC15PasswordManager14ViewController", referenced from:

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I am learning iOS and now have an issue building a UITest for an app. The code, pasted below, will compile if I remove the **var viewController: ViewController!** field, but fails when I add it. When I click on the error message, it takes me to the "Build Phases" portion of the PasswordManagerUITests project. I have include the screenshots of the error and the Build Phases for the project below.

```
import XCTest

@testable import PasswordManager

class ViewControllerTestCase: XCTestCase {

var viewController: ViewController!

override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()
}

override func tearDown() {
    // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
    super.tearDown()
}

func testExample() {
    // Use recording to get started writing UI tests.
    // Use XCTAssert and related functions to verify your tests produce the correct results.
}
```

}
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's because ViewController (it's a class within PasswordManager, right?) is not available on the UI test level. And it shouldn't be.
You don't need `@testable import PasswordManager` in UI test. In UI test you're testing UI elements (`XCUIElement` objects) only not classes from the app itself.

If you want to test your app classes then you want to write Unit test not UI test.